# Online Bookmarks

Tags: online

I want to save my bookmarks online so that I could access them from anywhere, from any computer.

So I want to know the site name or if there is any tool for it as I cant remember lots of site's name, which is useful for me.

Comment: Probably a question for [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) where it might already been answered. You should at least check.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for that.

Most notable websites include:

- [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/about/features/online_access)
- [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks)
- [QuickBookmarks](http://www.quickbookmarks.com/)
- [MyBookmarks](http://www.mybookmarks.com/)

But you can solve it also using the browser

- IE got few [different solutions](http://www.howtogeek.com/131249/how-to-synchronize-your-internet-explorer-favorites/), from in-system support to plugins
- In firefox you can use [Firefox Synch](https://account.services.mozilla.com/)
- In chrome you can use [Sign In](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139) feature

Browse through the links provided to find a best solution for your needs :)

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution.Can you please explain how can I use Firefox Synch?I have created my account in it.

Comment: Follow the tutorials on firefox website :) They got it quite nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out http://www.diigo.com. They have great plugins for all browsers along with other tools that make it a pleasure: adding notes to pages, saving pages, read it later functionality and more. It's also easy to set up and syncs across all your various computers.